# Install Android NDK on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-ndk

I wanted to install the Android NDK on my Jenkins. What I normally do to install components is execute the command

```
android list sdk --all
```

and

```
android update sdk -u -a -t <package number>
```

Unfortunately `android list sdk --all` is not showing the **NDK**, **CMake** and **LLDB** sdks that I need.

Why those sdks are not showing on the sdks list?

How can I install the NDK on my Jenkins?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the command line, you can simply download the NDK per your machine and unzip it to a directory wherever you like. NDK can be downloaded at: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads. All the components, e.g. NDK, CMake and LLDB are shipped inside.

**Update:** If you really want to go for command line approach, command [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) (under directory: `<your-path>/sdk/tools/bin`) is the way to go.

E.g. List installed and available packages

```
./sdkmanager --list
```

To install NDK directly use below.

```
./sdkmanager "ndk-bundle"
./sdkmanager "lldb;3.1"
./sdkmanager "cmake;3.6.4111459"
```